# Can I monitor a hidden value change in JSF/Seam?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

AS subject, can I do that like below in JSF 1.2/Richfaces 3.3:

`<h:inputHidden value="#{manageBean.value}">
  <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="contentID" eventsQueue="eventQueue" />
</h:inputHidden>`

The reason is that it reuquries to reRender a content area on page depends on a value change, this value is not changed by page codes (by the backened bean), So I want a change event for it.

Thank you advance.

Comment: In theory, you could. What's the motivation for this?

Comment: I gather that you're using JSF 1.x / RichFaces 3.x? In future questions, please explicitly mention the versions as well.

Comment: Yes, I am using JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3, thank you.

Comment: Updated the motivation to the decription.

Answer (score 3):

If that won't work you can try

```
<h:inputText id="myHidden" style="display:none" value="#{manageBean.value}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="contentID" eventsQueue="eventQueue" />
</h:inputText>
```

Also you will have to trigger manually its change event, for example with jQuery:

```
$("#myHidden").change(); //form or naming container prefix might be needed (`$("#myForm\\:myHidden").change();`)
```